# PhpUnit 9.6.16 with Drupal 10.2 unable to write to output directory: How to fix that error?

Tags: testing, 10

I have multiple sites running Drupal 10.1.7, all are using custom modules with appropriate functional tests. The tests are running fine.

Now, I wanted to update the sites to Drupal 10.2.2. This update also applied smoothly without any issues. But PhpUnit started to complain with the following error:

HTML output directory web/sites/simpletest/browser_output is not a writable directory.

Tests are still running ok [OK (9 tests, 85 assertions)], but no output is written to the configured output directory. The directory existed before, wasn't changed and still contains output from the last test using Drupal 10.1.7.

When reverting the site to Drupal 10.1.7, the error disappears again. So, I assume, it must have something to do with Drupal 10.2, but I couldn't find anything related in the changelogs.

Tests are running as user www-data and the directories "web/sites/simpletest" and "web/sites/simpletest/browser_output" belong to that user. Folder permissions have been set to 755 and 777 without fixing the error.

Directory is set with: `<env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="web/sites/simpletest/browser_output"/>`, but I also tried with `./web/sites/simpletest/browser_output` (alternative relative notation) and `/var/www/html/web/sites/simpletest/browser_output` (absolute path) to no avail.

Example output from one of the sites:

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit web/modules/custom
HTML output directory web/sites/simpletest/browser_output is not a writable directory.
PHPUnit 9.6.16 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.1.22
Configuration: /var/www/html/phpunit.xml

Testing /var/www/html/web/modules/custom
.........                                                           9 / 9 (100%)

Time: 01:09.421, Memory: 14.00 MB

OK (9 tests, 85 assertions)
```

It's identical in Drupal 10.1.7 but without the error in line 2.

### Update #1

I tried an incremental update. Tests are running fine and output is written to defined directory with 10.1.7 and 10.1.8, writing problems start with 10.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why this was changed, but starting with Drupal 10.2.0, the `BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable is no longer relative to the DOCROOT at `/var/www/html` but relative to the WEBROOT at `/var/www/html/web`.

Thus, the new line in my phpunit.xml file reads as follows and the error is gone.

`<env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="sites/simpletest/browser_output"/>`

Comment: Thanks! You save my time